# mongodb: modelling user defined sort order

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I am looking for a good way to implement a sort key, that is completely user definable. E.g. The user is presented with a list and may sort the elements by dragging them around. This order should be persisted.

One commonly used way is to just create an ascending integer type sort field within each element:

```
{
    "_id": "xxx1",
    "sort": 2
},
{
    "_id": "xxx2",
    "sort": 3
},
{
    "_id": "xxx3",
    "sort": 1
}
```

While this will surely work, it might not be ideal: In case the user moves an element from the very bottom to the very top, all the indexes in-between need to be updated. We are not talking about embedded documents here, so this will cause a lot of individual documents to be updated. This might be optimised by creating initial sort values with gaps in-between (e.g. 100, 200, 300, 400). However, this will create the need for additional logic an re-sorting in case the space between two elements is exhausted.

Another approach comes to mind: Have the parent document contain a sorted array, which defines the order of the children.

```
{
  "_id": "parent01",
  "children": ["xxx3","xxx1","xxx2"]
}
```

This approach would certainly make it easier to change the order, but will have it's own caveats: The parent documents must always keep track of a valid list of its children. As adding children will update multiple documents, this still might not be ideal. And there needs to be complex validation of the input received from the client, as the length of this list and the elements contained, may never be changed by the client.

Is there a better way to implement such a use case?

Comment: The second option seems to me much more efficient and feasible. What do you mean by complex validation of the input received from the client"? If you just want to check if the client is using valid elements, you can have a second separate collection with only the valid elements for checking this. Also, mongodb will soon have the 'insert at index' option (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2363) in the production release.

Comment: Thanks, that issue would only arise in case the client would be allowed to send an updated list, not if the client sends the necessary steps to recreated the updated list. However, you should probably submit that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say which option is better without knowing:

1. How often the sort order is usually updated
2. Which queries you gonna run against the documents and how often
3. How many documents can be sorted at a time

I'm sure you gonna do much more queries than updates so personally I would go with the first option. It's easy to implement and it's simple which means it's gonna be rebust. I understand your concerns about updating multiple documents but the updates will be done in place, I mean no documents shifting will occur as you don't actually change the documents size. Just create a simple test. Generate 1k of documents, then just update each of them in a loop like that

```
db.test.update({ '_id': arrIds[i] }, { $set: { 'sort' : i } })
```

You will see it will be a pretty instant operation.

I like the second option as well, from programming perspective it looks more elegant but when it comes to practice you don't usually care much if your update takes 10 milleseconds instead of 5 if you don't do it often and I'm sure you don't, most applications are query oriented.

**EDIT:**
When you update multiple documents, even if it's an instant operation, one may come up with an inconsistency issue when some documents are updated and some not. In my case it wasn't really an issue in fact. Let's consider an example, assume there's a list:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sort" : 1 },{ "_id" : 2, "sort" : 4 },{ "_id" : 3, "sort" : 2 },{ "_id" : 4, "sort" : 3 }
```

so the ordered ids should look like that **1,3,4,2** according to sort fields. Let's say we have a failure when we want to move id=2 to the top. The failure occurs when we only updated two documents, so we will come up with the following state as we only managed to update ids 2 and 1:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sort" : 2 },{ "_id" : 2, "sort" : 1 },{ "_id" : 3, "sort" : 2 },{ "_id" : 4, "sort" : 3 }
```

the data is in inconsistent state but still we can display the list to fix the problem, the ids order will be **2,1,3,4** if we just order it by sort field. why is it not a problem in my case? because when a failure occurs a user is redirected to an error page or provided with an error message, it is obvious for him that something got wrong and he should try again, so he just goes to the page and fix the order which is only partially valid for him.

Just to sum it up. Taking into account that it's a really rare case and other benefits of the approach I would go with it. Otherwise you will have to place everything in one document both the elements and the array with their indexes. This might be a much bigger issue, especially when it come to querying.

Hope it helps!

Comment: surely I will have quite more queries than updates. The concern I am having with multi document updates is not that they may take long, but that things could possibly go wrong somewhere and as long as you don't implement transactional behaviour yourself, this could leave you with corrupt data. However, as for document based data modelling, there usually is a nice solution, which you probably wouldn't think of without a lot experience in that field. That's why I was asking.

Comment: actually I had the same issue and just wanted to share what I learned from it, I couldn't find or come up with a better solution and I'll be really glad if someone suggest a better on here. Regarding consistency issue, you are absolutley correct here but in my case it wasn't really important. It's very unlikely to happen and even if it does it will not corrupt the data. But probably for your solution it's vital. Sorry I wouldn't have agitated for the first option it just had not been clear enough for me, that consistency is important here.

Comment: well, in case something goes wrong when updating the sort values, you most likely will end up with the same sort value used more than once, which at least would lead to an undefined sort order for two elements.  If that will effectively be a problem depends on the expectations of the user and how well the application deals with such a case. At least it will lead to an inconsistency, which almost always is some sort of a bad thing. I think best thing is to try to avoid multi document updates when possible. But I haven't hit production yet, so that's hypothetical in some way.

Comment: see my update, I tried to describe why it wasn't an issue in mu case

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Makes sense. You actually enabled your application to deal with such a state. Still, I like the other approach as it removes the need for multi document updates. However, it will be more work to sort the actual entities according to the order that is stored in the parent. Probably we'll be lucky and someone will still chime in with another approach.

Comment: Yeah, would be interesting to find a new approach. Just out of curiosity, what's your solution now? how does your document look like?

Comment: That's not decided yet. Unless I come across a really good idea, that probably won't happen within the next few weeks, as this is for a feature that I currently don't prioritize very high.

Comment: After thinking some more about this, I think I will just solve this issue by embedding the whole child documents within the parent. The children just contain about 5 or 6 fields. Most of them are just ObjectIds, boolean or integers. Together with the upcoming feature joao mentioned, this should be a pretty viable solution, which might even save me some queries. It might create quite some differently sized parent documents though.